# Spring HATEOAS add external content while deserializing JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, hateoas

I'm creating a client to query our JSON Api and I'm trying to extend a resource with the content coming from another resource. I want to do this because the resources are part of the same entity and our users will get back the single entity without the need to query the two services separately. 
I'll put here a base version of the resources, to better explain the problem:

```java
/* Sample class */
public class Sample {

    public String accession;
    public String name;
    //...
    public Map<RelationType, List<Relation>> relations
    // ... classic getters and setters
}

// Relation class 
public class Relation {
    public String id;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now the JSON Api is something similar to this:
Here the Sample

```js
{  
    "_embedded":{  
        "samples":[  
            {  
                "accession":"SAME1500861",
                "name":"1380435",
                "_links":{  
                    "self":{      "href":"https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samples/SAME1500861"
                    },
                    "sample":{  
                        "href":"https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samples/SAME1500861"
                    },
                    "relations":{  
                        "href":"https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links":{ }
}
```

Here the relations:

```js
{
  "accession": "SAME1500861",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861"
    },
    "derivedFrom": {
      "href": "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861/derivedFrom"
    },
    "derivedTo": {
      "href": "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861/derivedTo"
    },
    "externalLinks": {
      "href": "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861/externalLinks"
    },
    "recuratedTo": {
      "href": "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861/recuratedTo"
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Correct me please if I'm wrong...
You want to make a call one time but have full parsed json object ?

Comment: No I just want to combine the two JSON resources into the Sample class during the Sample JSON resource parsing. I think I need to do two calls in any case since the resources are separated

Comment: I would use Gson and call setRelations method of class Sample  after parse

Comment: There's a way to hook into Spring auto-parsing?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a Java class structure that represents the data in your JSON. You can use any of online viewers or some chrome extension to see stricture...

I've just done small part of your relations JSON...

```
public class Relations {

    public String accession;
    public Links _links;
}

public class Links {
    public Self self;
}

public class Self {
    public String href;
}
```

Here at least 2 option in my eyes...

1. Retrive JSON as string and convert via Gson
2. Use spring RestTemplate

Basically I would recommend to use Spring RestTemplate

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

Relations result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861", Relations.class);
```

Or you can use any lib to get JSON response and convert via Gson

```
    String relationsPart = "{\n" + "  \"accession\": \"SAME1500861\",\n" + "  \"_links\": {\n" + "    \"self\": {\n" + "      \"href\": \"https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biosamples/api/samplesrelations/SAME1500861\"\n" + "    }\n" + "  }\n" + "}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Relations result = gson.fromJson(relationsPart, Relations.class);
```

Comment: I'm already using RestTemplate and using a Resource as object to retrieve Spring is already able to model the links. Here the problem is the relations is another resource in spring, so I need another GET request to get it. But I don't know if I can hook inside Jackson parsing of the Sample resource to do a second query and retrieve also the Relation Resource. I'm afraid the answer to this question is no

Comment: That was my second comment, why not after parse Sample resource make second request and then call setRelations method ?

Comment: Yes, but there's no need to use GSON to do this if you're using restTemplate + Spring + Jackson. Am I right?

Comment: if you already using RestTemplate yes, but in that time I didn't know what you chosen.